# Return previous or next enabled sibling of same parent

Tags: previous-next

I want to link to enabled sibling entries within a structure and am struggling to get it working.

This is what my structure looks like:

[image]

Because I only want to fetch entries that are enabled, I followed the docs instructions and fetch previous entries like this:

```
{% set prevEntry = craft.entries.positionedBefore(entry).order('lft desc').first() %}
```

With this, when on the `Prince Phillip` entry, I thought that would return `null` for `prevEntry`, but it is returning the `Altynia Asylmoratova` entry.

How can I fetch previous and next entries that are **direct siblings and enabled**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After trying a few more things, I realised I needed the `descendantOf` parameter to get this working.

This is what my code looks like:

```
{% set prevEntry = craft.entries.descendantOf(entry.parent).positionedBefore(entry).order('lft desc').first() %}
{% if prevEntry is null %}
  {% set prevEntry = entry.siblings.last() %}
{% endif %}

{% set nextEntry = craft.entries.descendantOf(entry.parent).positionedAfter(entry).first() %}
{% if nextEntry is null %}
  {% set nextEntry = entry.siblings.first() %}
{% endif %}
```

This restricts the `positionedBefore` and `positionedAfter` parameters to only work with entries that have the same parent as the current entry.

If there is no previous or next entry, I link to the first or last sibling entry instead, creating a loop.